# Matching date in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code to match dates.

Code:

```
    strDate1 = Sheets("Part2").Cells(i, 1).Value
    date1 = DateSerial(Left(strDate1, 4), Mid(strDate1, 3, 2), Right(strDate1, 2))
    srtDate2 = Format(DateAdd("yyyy", -1, date1), "yyyymmdd")
    matchStartRow = Application.Match(CDbl(srtDate2), Sheets("1.A").Range("A:A"), 1)
    If IsError(matchStartRow) Then
        matchStartRow = 3
    Else
        matchStartRow = matchStartRow + 1
    End If
```

If dates match, matchstartrow should remain as it. If it doesn't match, it need to add one. How to incorporate this? Code seems to be wrong..

Need some guidance to modify this..

code for this was obtained from:[How to get date - 1 year in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746584/how-to-get-date-1-year-in-vba)

Comment: can youclarify what exactly wrong? If your dates are _sorted in ascending order_, code should works

Comment: wrong in the sense, if it finds a match in the column A. the row should the matched rownumber. If not it should add 1 to the rownumber.. it is adding one always..

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, let me fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
strDate1 = Sheets("Part2").Cells(i, 1).Value
date1 = DateSerial(Left(strDate1, 4), Mid(strDate1, 3, 2), Right(strDate1, 2))
srtDate2 = Format(DateAdd("yyyy", -1, date1), "yyyymmdd")
'trying to find EXACT match
matchStartRow = Application.Match(CDbl(srtDate2), Sheets("1.A").Range("A:A"), 0)
If IsError(matchStartRow) Then
    'If exact match not found, searching for approx match
    matchStartRow = Application.Match(CDbl(srtDate2), Sheets("1.A").Range("A:A"), 1)
    If IsError(matchStartRow) Then
        'if approx match not found - that's means that target date is less than all dates in Sheets("1.A").Range("A:A"), so we get 3rd row with first date
        matchStartRow = 3
    Else
        'if approx match is found we add 1 to get first date greater than target
        matchStartRow = matchStartRow + 1
    End If
End If
```

or also this one should work:

```
strDate1 = Sheets("Part2").Cells(i, 1).Value
date1 = DateSerial(Left(strDate1, 4), Mid(strDate1, 3, 2), Right(strDate1, 2))
srtDate2 = Format(DateAdd("yyyy", -1, date1), "yyyymmdd")
matchStartRow = Application.Match(CDbl(srtDate2), Sheets("1.A").Range("A:A"), 1)
If IsError(matchStartRow) Then
    matchStartRow = 3
Else
    'if we found exact match, add 0, else add 1
    matchStartRow = matchStartRow + IIf(Sheets("1.A").Range("A" & matchStartRow).Value = CDbl(srtDate2), 0, 1)
End If
```